# How to display more text in LyX ? Make the page wider ?

Tags: latex, margin, document, lyx

How to display more text in LyX ? Make the page wider ? 
I have a document in A4 paper, but I am out of page limit now. How I can make the page wider ? I mean, how to make each line with more words ? I have changed my font size. How I can change the margin of the A4 paper in Lyx ?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Document > Settings > Page Margins. Uncheck "Default Margins" and change them to what you want manually.